# Set CloudWatch timers as a resource using the Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework

I'm using the Serverless Framework v1.9

I have a number of Lambda functions that require minimal latency. The current best-practice appears to be setting up CloudWatch timers to ping the functions so they stay warm, as you can read in this blog post: [How to Keep Your Lambda Functions Warm](https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm-9d7e1aa6e2f0).

Currently, I'm manually setting up these timers after I deploy a new function, but ideally I would like to set up a cloudwatch timer as a resource that automatically gets deployed with each function.

Is this possible? Is this something that will ever be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to *automatically* deploy a new CloudWatch resource to avoid the hassle of *manually* setting a resource and to avoid forgetting to configure them sometimes.

In this case, the current framework does not provide an *automatic* solution for that, you would need a *manual* configuration through CloudFormation stacks. You would need to add a plugin to keep this task simple and I believe that no one has created one for that (yet).

However, instead of keeping your functions warm with CloudWatch, you could use a Lambda schedule to trigger all other functions. This setting is quite good and there is already a [plugin](https://github.com/FidelLimited/serverless-plugin-warmup) for that. You can read detailed instructions in this [blog post](https://serverless.com/blog/keep-your-lambdas-warm/).

**In summary:**

Install the plugin

```
npm install serverless-plugin-warmup --save-dev
```

Reference the plugin in the **serverless.yml** file

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-warmup
```

Add `warmup: true` for all functions that you want to keep warm

```
functions:
  hello:
    warmup: true
```

Comment: That's just what I was looking for! Thank you!